# What aspects of GR should be taken into consideration for realistic visualizations of a Kerr black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, simulations, visualization

I am not 100% sure if these kinds of questions are allowed, if not sorry in advance.

For the past year, me and a friend have been working on a render engine to visualize a Kerr black hole. We have come quiet far and current results look like this;

[image]

[image]

We ultimately plan to write a paper about the process and showcase the pitfalls we fell into and the solutions to a whole range of problems. But we have also kind of run out of ideas of effects to implement. To give a breakdown of what this engine considers;

- Kerr Metric; We solve the equations of motion using an RKF45 scheme, takes about 2 seconds for a 2000x1000 pixel image with no accretion disk (break condition at the Horizon is $r < r_+ * 1.0001$)
- Blackbody Emission; The disk is colored using a function which converts a given Temperature into an RGB color using Planck's law, which boils down to a for loop over all visual wavelengths
- Relativistic Redshift; We have a very generalized function for redshift which takes into account the orbital velocity of the disk, motion of the camera and the gravitational redshift
- Doppler Beaming; This one was tricky, because getting beaming to work for an optically thick disk is a bit occult, but it works now and matches other simulations with dense disks
- Light travel delay / Time Dilation; The disk spins in accordance wit the time coordinate and a delay angle. In essence the side of the disk approaching the observer appears Stretched out, while the side receding appears compressed
- Aberration of Light / Non-Stationary Camera; In the renders above, the camera has almost no momentum, and the math does not assume the camera to be stationary. So for instance, even if the momentum is 0, but the camera is inside the Ergo sphere, aberration will distort the image heavily
- Orbital Velocities; The rate of rotation for the disk is given by a function that produces circular orbits. So the shorter r is, the faster the disk spins
- ZAMO; The Zero Angular Momentum Observer allows for the disk, and camera, to be within the Ergo sphere and neither redshift nor beaming to explode. Without ZAMO the apparent velocities inside the ergo sphere can go above c.
- Infinitely spinning disk; This one was a hassle, but in essence the disk will maintain its structure and not visually distort as time advances, which is quiet important for time dilation (Though do note, the disk boils down to a Voronoi and Perlin noise texture)

This is pretty much where we stand right now. Note, in these renders the disk has a temperature of on average 1600 Kelvin, and we use the Stefan–Boltzmann law to scale the brightness of the disk by the apparent Temperature. Hence why it looks so dark on the right side. Furthermore, in these renders the spin parameter is at -0.999.

There are some visual aspects we want to add, such as a relativistic jet, but those do not really entail holy new physics.

Rather we wonder if there are any other effects which should be implemented. Of course there is an argument that non of this is really realistic because one of the core visual elements, the accretion disk, is not simulated outside of 156 points which are used to construct a coordinate system for the procedural noise textures. So the motion of the disk is accurate, but the overall appreance is a best guess sort of deal.

Regardless, I am sure we have missed some effect which would change the visuals at least to an extend. This is the question at its core, what other effects should be taken into consideration?

I am aware, this is a very general question and most suggestions (assuming the post does not get nuked) will be very "niche" and relate to the disk in some capacity. I read a few papers which suggest Electron / charge density are very important for the appreance, which atm is not accounted for. If it is stuff like this, that's fine. The issue we have is that we are just 2 dudes with a limited horizon. So if anyone can look at this and say "You missed XYZ" then that's great.

If anyone wants to look at the code, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4gm6rzolqo91fhqo30nby/Kerr.txt?rlkey=lbsug3pl3o4vba0wduq3mamz0&dl=0) ya go. Note, this program is written in VEX, which is a mix between Python and OpenGL.

So yeah, thanks for reading, thanks for any suggestions and i hope this question did not violate any rules.

Comment: A note on the title, GR is a generalization of SR so to ask what aspects of both should be included is a bit redundant.

Comment: Hi ErikHall. Welcome to Phys.SE. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Comment: I think this is interesting, but I don't think you should limit yourselves to the numerics. I have not seen what you linked, but there are papers (such as 2301.09549) that do numerical calculations and analyze the behavior of these simulations. I would suggest (I am only a theorist!) that you take into account of numerical relativity more deeply, see for instance 1208.3927 and gr-qc/0703035 for a general review of decomposition. There are many geometric aspects as well to consider if you are writing a paper, and as of the question, well, I will try to see what has been done and add them here.

Comment: I am stunned and mortified that I cannot claim my karma for steering you towards this as the question is closed :)  https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03808  Those are the people who can (maybe) best point you in the right direction.  I can provide you with a better integrator than RK4 or whatever, but that is the least of your "challenges" ;)  I'll take a look at the code (maybe GitHub or somehwhere public is a better place for it) as this is an interest of mine.